# Ubuntu 20.04.6 external display doesn't work on my new laptop

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I got a new XPS 15 9530 with following specs;

- i9 13th gen
- RTX 4070
- 3.5k OLED Display

I turned off secure boot and install Ubuntu 20.04.6 and I keep facing some problems. I think I have a driver problem. I try following solutions but none of them works:

1. I select NVIDIA 525 all options from additional drivers but none of them works
2. I try x.org driver but it doesn't work too
3. I download 530 from NVIDIA website and install but doesn't work
4. I update grub with `quiet splash` to `quiet splash nomodeset` but doesn't work
5. I try perfomance mode over nvidia-prime but it gives black screen on startup. I redo from recovery mode
6. I update kernel to `5.15.0-69-generic` but nothing changed
7. I did `purge` and `autoremove` for NVIDIA but nothing changed again

When I go to Display on settings, my screen shown like 'Unknown Display' with 3456x2160 resolution. I also want to use with 1080 but there is no option like this. I try to add resolution from terminal with following code:

`sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  272.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1127 -hsync +vsync`

But I got following error:

`xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`

I am trying to connect to external monitor with a type-c to hdmi converter. I try with several converter but none of them works. I feel like all about drivers but I couldn't figure out how to use external display. I am not professional on Ubuntu. Can you please guide me towards and appropriate solution?

EDIT:

My laptop's motherboard model number:

| Manufacturer | Product | SerialNumber | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dell Inc. | 0PHRDD | /HRZYTV3/CNCMK0033F039F/ | A00 |

Comment: What is the model number on your motherboard?

Comment: I edit question with motherboard informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the Nvidia 530 driver, which will be supported by Ubuntu 23.04 natively. The NVIDIA drivers only work with certain kernels, thus you installed a driver that will not work with your old kernel.
So your best bet is to upgrade at least to Ubuntu 22.04, install the latest NVIDIA driver (530) and report back.

Someone else had a [similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464468/does-the-nvidia-rtx-4070-have-drivers-for-ubuntu-22-04) in this forum -just 7 days ago.

Comment: I already install 530 and latest kernel for 20.04. I will upgrade ubuntu 22 and will see

Comment: Now I have ubuntu 22.04.2 and kernel 5.15.0-71-generic with NVIDIA 530 but no result. Also wifi not working now.

Comment: Everything works fine now with kernel 6.3-generic. I edit your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When having the latest hardware, you need the latest kernels as well.