# Does the NVIDIA RTX 4070 have drivers for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

After installing an RTX 4070 (MSI Ventus 2x) in my PC, the list of `Additional Drivers` in `Software & Updates` is empty, and Ubuntu 22.04 seems to recognize the GPU as some generic NVIDIA graphics, but doesn't recognize an RTX 4070 specifically. E.g.

```
⮕ hwinfo --gfxcard --short
graphics card:                                                  
                       nVidia VGA compatible controller

Primary display adapter: #13
```

and also

```
⮕ lspci | grep -e VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2786 (rev a1)
```

Even after adding the necessary [Jammy PPA](https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/), no suitable graphics driver is found; this returns nothing:

```
⮕ ubuntu-drivers devices
⮕
```

In spite of that, I do get a functioning desktop, but the performance of the GPU are terrible, the RTX 4070 is on par with, or worse than, a previous GTX 1080 I had, as reported by three different benchmarks (Unigine Superposition, glmark2, Blender).

I have downloaded the latest released drivers ver. 525.105.17 for Linux from the NVIDIA web site, and installed them manually (running the .run file) but the situation is the same as before. Also, I couldn't find mention to the RTX 4070 in the release notes.

The same card performs as expected under Win 10.

Is there any NVIDIA driver for their RTX 4070 under Ubuntu 22.04?

If you are successfully using an RTX 4070 with Ubuntu 22.04 (or any other Ubuntu version), what version of NVIDIA drivers have you installed, and how?

Comment: You are not using the most recent driver. nvidia-driver-530 is available for 22.10.  I was using it successfully with a RTX-3080.  Ubuntu 23.04 only has nvidia-driver-525 at this time.

This is from 23.04:

lspci | grep -e VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080 Lite Hash Rate] (rev a1)

Comment: I have just found drivers 530.41.03 have been recently been added for download from NVIDIA web site, and those seem to support the RTX 4070, as I am now getting the expected performances from benchmarks. NVIDIA indicates it as a feature branch release https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/current-graphics-driver-releases/28500

Answer (score 1):

I have a Zotac 4070 and it works fine if you manually install the 525 driver from the command line.   There is a mistake in the list Nvidia provided, whereby the exact match for the 4070 is missing. Hence Ubuntu-drivers does not find anything and the card is identified as "unknown".

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525 nvidia-dkms-525
```

and don't forget to blacklist nouveau.
Hope this Helps.
Zeb...

Comment: Have you tried running some graphics benchmark? E.g. Superposition? With drivers version 525, I have found performances were comparable to my old GTX 1080. I have downloaded and installed the 530.41.03 divers from NVIDIA's website, and got much better performances. E.g. with Superposition at 2560x1440, with Shaders Quality Extreme and Textures Quality High. DoF and motion blur enabled, I got a score of 5378 with average of 40.23 FPS with drivers 530, but got 1725 with average of 12.91 FPS with drivers 525

Comment: Mr Benchmarking, is generally done in game.  I only play World of Warships and over my old 2080Ti I have seen a 30 FPS increase at Max in game settings and running screen native 5120x1440.  Given WoWs is so old and poorly coded - lol.  I am satisfied with that.